# currentBuild.changeSets cut message by commit in pipeline Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

When build job jenkins generate changelog. But every commit message cut ~72 char with start in new line.

When i get message from currentBuild.changeSets in string set only first line of commit.

Jenkins pipeline:

```
node {

    stage 'clean'
    //step([$class: 'WsCleanup'])

    stage 'git'
    git url: 'https://***@***/***/****.git'

   stage 'change'
   passedBuilds = []

  lastSuccessfulBuild(passedBuilds, currentBuild);

  def changeLog = getChangeLog(passedBuilds)
  echo "${changeLog}"

}
def lastSuccessfulBuild(passedBuilds, build) {
if ((build != null) && (build.result != 'SUCCESS')) {
  passedBuilds.add(build)
}
}

@NonCPS
def getChangeLog(passedBuilds) {
    def log = ""
    for (int x = 0; x < passedBuilds.size(); x++) {
        def currentBuild = passedBuilds[x];
        def changeLogSets = currentBuild.changeSets
        for (int i = 0; i < changeLogSets.size(); i++) {
            def entries = changeLogSets[i].items
            for (int j = 0; j < entries.length; j++) {
                def entry = entries[j]
                def hasSummaryMatch = (entry.msg =~ /(#[0-9]{4})/)
                if (hasSummaryMatch) {
                    def numberTask = hasSummaryMatch[0][0]
                    numberTask = numberTask.replace('#', '')
                    def message = entry.msg
                    echo numberTask
                    log += "- [${numberTask}](......) ${message}\n"
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return log;
}
```

If see changes by build commit have multiline

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGiqg.png)

```
Summary

    changelog (details)
    #3157 очень длинный текст, который Jenkins разобьет на 2 строчки. Надо (details)

Commit 49b31854deb27bd13edf6fde33283cb1af8aab89 by fenix_ex

#3157 очень длинный текст, который Jenkins разобьет на 2 строчки. Надо
проверить правильную склейку строк при сборке обновления. А то очень не
красиво получается
```

how can i get full text commit?

p.s. `git log` show full message at 1 line.

Comment: How about using something like `sh (script: "git log --format='%ae' hash", returnStdout: true)` for each commit in the changelog and then matching?